# Is there a way to copy a user profile to other client stations previously not logged into?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-7, user-profile

I was wondering what would be the easiest way to copy a user profile to a station that user has not previoulsy signed on in an Active Directoy environment.  This would include anything that appears under the user's user folder under `C:\users` and registry entries associated with the user.  The stations being copied to are practically clones to each other.

Comment: oops, I let a unix slash slip in there.

Comment: are you doing this to avoid shared storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never tested, but you have to :
1 - copy the user's folder (with the same permissions, beware : they are not the same for some files) - often found in `C:\users\` or `C:\Documents and Settings\`
2 - copy the user's profile key (with the same permissions again) - found in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\`

Already tested :
1 - ask the user to log on the new computer
2 - do the steps explained previously
3 - ask the user to log on, to be sure everything is okay

Answer (score 1):

I've used Forensit's tools before with luck:

http://www.forensit.com/move-computer.html